# Softlayer API suddenly returned 'Order is missing the following category: Operating System' by flavor provision

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I used POST https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest.json.
wieh paras:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "blockDeviceTemplateGroup": {
        "globalIdentifier": "ea065435-f7ec-4f1c-8f3f-2987086b1427"
      },
      "datacenter": {
        "name": "lon02"
      },
      "dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag": false,
      "domain": "softlayer.com",
      "hostname": "test-20171117-034434-485",
      "hourlyBillingFlag": true,
      "localDiskFlag": true,
      "networkComponents": [
        {
          "maxSpeed": 100
        }
      ],
      "primaryBackendNetworkComponent": {
        "networkVlan": {
          "id": 1292651,
          "networkSpace": "PRIVATE"
        }
      },
      "primaryNetworkComponent": {
        "networkVlan": {
          "id": 1292653,
          "networkSpace": "PUBLIC"
        }
      },
      "privateNetworkOnlyFlag": false,
      "supplementalCreateObjectOptions": {
        "flavorKeyName": "BL1_1X2X100"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

API returned error: `SoftLayer_Exception_Public: Order is missing the following category: Operating System. (HTTP 500)`

Is is some properties I missed? I verified this method was worked last week.

Answer (score 0):

this is an issue with the API, I have already reported the issue some couple ago, but they did not fix it yet. you can report the issue as well by opening a ticket in the control portal

Comment: Hi, Did SoftLayer has any process about this?

Comment: well I reported the issue into its Jira system, but they did not start work on the fix for the issue,  as I told you in my answer you can report the issue by submitting an ticket in https://control.softlayer.com/ in that way can you press them more than me in order to get a fix fast. I really recomend you to open the ticket.